# How to define integration for general functions?

Tags: integration

In general, the integration is defined on a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, where $X$ is the whole space, $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, and measure $\mu$. Usually integration is defined for real-valued function $f$ or complex-value function, (which is essentially same as real-valued one). Formally, integration on a subset of $E\subset X$ is a function from ring of measurable functions to $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\int_E: f(a) \to \mathbb{R}
$$

I am wondering if there is any research or related results on somewhat more general settings. For example, $f$ is a map from $X$ to some Ring $R$ and $\int_E$ is defined to be a map from the ring of $R$-valued functions to Ring $R$.

In order to make it more "useful", it's better to related this definite integration to some formal indefinite integrations such as [discussed here](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/math-2017-0034/html?lang=en)

Comment: What problem would you solve with such a definition? The question is more interesting if you have some particular use for it.

Comment: The ring structure plays no role here. The function you integrate can take values in a topological vector space. See N. Bourbaki, Integration.